# A good way to detect swipe right and show the animation when dragging the

Tags: react-native

In my detail scroll view, I detect the gesture and go back to previous navigation.

However, The go back will happen immediately. Unlike most app will have a animation to peek/preview the previous view.

How to enable this in react-native?
Also, the swipe right detect is not so user-friendly.

Here's my algorithm.
Any idea to make it more smoothly?

```
onPanResponderMove(event, gestureState)  {
    if(event.nativeEvent.changedTouches.length===1){
        // x 位移
        let diffX = gestureState.dx - this.lastPositionX
        if (this.lastPositionX === null) {
            diffX = 0
        }
        // y 位移
        let diffY = gestureState.dy - this.lastPositionY
        if (this.lastPositionY === null) {
            diffY = 0
        }
        if(diffX > 5 && Math.abs(diffY) < 10 ){
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
        }
        // 保留这一次位移作为下次的上一次位移
        this.lastPositionX = gestureState.dx
        this.lastPositionY = gestureState.dy
    }
}
```

[image: inline]